# Ubuntu 14.04 no internet access with my laptop

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I have looked at askubuntu for answer but still I cannot resolve my problem.My ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:b3:42:05:5c  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:171 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:171 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12241 (12.2 KB)  TX bytes:12241 (12.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:00:b2:16:48  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ ping -c3 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.029/0.032/0.034/0.002 ms
```

And lshw network

```
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:98200000-98203fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:86:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:25:b3:42:05:5c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:30 memory:90100000-90103fff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90120000-9013ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 00:21:00:b2:16:48
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=3.19.0-47-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

How to solve this?

Following Hennes advice,with sudo

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:b3:42:05:5c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:12f0:784:df66:225:b3ff:fe42:55c/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:b3ff:fe42:55c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:108270 (108.2 KB)  TX bytes:9117 (9.1 KB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:482 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:482 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:37222 (37.2 KB)  TX bytes:37222 (37.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:00:b2:16:48  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I should just add my lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4312 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [103c:137d]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at 98200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Neither eth0 nor waln0 have an IP. Did you even configure a network? Do yuou use DHCP ans if you do, did you enable it?

Comment: @Hennes I have formated my laptop,and have configured network.After that I was removing some packages,so problems occur at that moment.

Comment: @Hennes How to enable DHCP?

Comment: I suspect you may have removed to much. Try bringing up the network (at least until reboot) in the old fashioned way: `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0` and see if you can ping your networks gateway. (Adjust IP numbers and netmask if appropriate.  If that works add a route to the default gateway, probably via something like this: `route add default gw 192.168.1.1 eth0`. (UNTESTED, no access to an Ubunto host atm.)  This shouyld atleast give you your network back and allow you to do some emergency repairs.

Comment: Alternative attempt: `dhclient eth0`, but I fear that this is something you might have unstalled. Hence the manual entries above.

Comment: @Hennes  ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 I got SIOCSIFADDR:Operation not permitted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35645/discussion-between-hennes-and-richard-rublev).

Answer (score 0):

You can install the bcmwl-kernel-source package from the restricted folder under ../pool/restricted/b/bcmwl on the Ubuntu install media.

To find out your current kernel use the command:

```
 uname -r
```

To find what linux-headers packages you have installed use the command:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep headers
```

Systems installed from CDROM can add the install CD as a package source and install bcmwl-kernel-source using apt-get . However, if you want to do it manually then the instructions are as follows:

Navigate the install media and install the packages listed below by double clicking OR install the packages consecutively from a Terminal (in the commands below the install media is mounted at /cdrom, but yours maybe different):

1 ) /pool/main/d/dkms

```
  cd /cdrom/pool/main/d/dkms
  sudo dpkg -i dkms*
```

2) /pool/main/p/patch

```
  cd /cdrom/pool/main/p/patch
  sudo dpkg -i patch*
```

3) /pool/main/f/fakeroot

```
  cd /cdrom/pool/main/f/fakeroot
  sudo dpkg -i fakeroot*
```

4) /pool/restricted/b/bcmwl

```
 cd /cdrom/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl
 sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source*
```

Install the b43-fwcutter package. This is usually located on the Ubuntu install media under /cdrom/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/ 
Double click on the package to install or in a Terminal issue the following commands:

```
 cd /cdrom/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/
 sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter* 

 sudo modprobe -r b43 bcma
```

Reboot

Comment: Downloading the drive might be tricky, seeing as how the OP has no IP on either wired or wireless.

Comment: @GAD3R I have tried but could not achieve.It starts but then goes to Do not use this device button.